# using names of places in if statements or enumerating variables

Tags: java

I'm making a program that calculates final sale price for items purchased based on a state's sales tax. The program will prompt the user for the name of the state. So if I prompt the user with joptionpane and the user inputs Alaska:

```
double State = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter state"));
```

> user inputs Alaska

then I would have an `if` statement for each state to perform the arithmetic based on the sales tax of that state like:

```
if (State == Alaska) 
{
    then blah blah blah
}
```

The problem is that I get an unrecognized symbol error at Alaska because it's not a number. So how can I make an if statement recognize each state by a number to be used in an if statement.

like setting `Alaska = 1` so I can later say

```
if (State == 1) {blah blah tax calculations
```

Also if there is a better way to do this I am all ears.

Comment: **WHY** would `State` be a `double`??? It's clearly a `String`.

Comment: It seems to me that hard-coding names and/or sales tax percentages for 50 states is a poor idea.  Would a properties file work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Store the selection as a `java.lang.String`, for example -

```
String state = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter state");
if ("Alaska".equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
  // it's Alaska.
}
```

You certainly could also check it against an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), but the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is where I suggest you start.